# Is there any .NET Framework 4 API or library for using Bluetooth to communicate between computers?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm programming a Tic Tac Toe in C# and I would like to make it easy to play between two notebooks. So I think it would be great to make this game able to be played through the bluetooth connection.

My question is - is there any .NET Framework 4 API or library for using Bluetooth to do this? I've looked for it a bit but I'm afraid that maybe there's no way to do it simply.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Normally you would set up a PAN, and then ordinary TCP/IP sockets would work at the application layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [32feet.NET](http://inthehand.com/content/32feet.aspx) for working with bluetooth devices.